# Why the Red Black Tree is kept unbalanced after insertion?

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

[Here](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/undergraduate/341/spring04/hood/notes/red_black/) is a red black tree which seems unbalanced. If this is the case, Someone please explain **why it is unbalanced?**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "balanced" is a bit ambiguous, since different kinds of balanced trees have different constraints.

A red-black tree ensures that every path to a leaf has the same number of black nodes, and at least as many black nodes as red nodes.  The result is that the longest path is at most twice as long as the shortest path, which is good enough to guarantee O(log N) time for search, insert, and delete operations.

Most other kinds of balanced trees have tighter balancing constraints.  An AVL tree, for example, ensures that the lengths of the longest paths on either side of every node differ by at most 1.  This is more than you need, and that has costs -- inserting or deleting in an AVL tree (after finding the target node) takes O(log N) operations on average, while inserting or deleting in a red-black tree takes O(1) operations on average.

If you wanted to keep a tree *completely balanced*, so that you had the same number of descendents on either side of every node, +/- 1, it would be very expensive -- insert and delete operations would take O(N) time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is balanced. The rule says, counting the black NIL leaves, the longest possible path should consists maximum of 2*B-1 nodes where B is black nodes in shortest possible path from the root  to any leaf. In your example shortest path has 2 black nodes so B = 2 so longest path can have upto 3 black nodes but it is just 2.

Comment: sorry i didn't get it :(  Where can i read about this rules in detail ?